# base_url() gives wrong link if inside href attribute

Tags: php, codeigniter, href, environment

I just started to learn Codeigniter 3.1.7, when I encountered something strange.

My site is installed in a subdirectory `domain.com/site1`, while the following happens:

```
<h1><?php echo base_url(); ?></h1>
```

This prints **domain.com/site1/**

```
<h1><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Link</a></h1>
```

This generates a href = **domain.com/site1/domain.com/site1**

How is this possible? What am I missing?

Comment: > What am I missing? "http://"

Comment: Could you please explain why without `http` the string is returned twice?

Comment: It's not returned twice. If you don't specify the protocol or "//", the browser treats it as a relative url, automatically prefixing it with the domain and path.

Comment: I have 1+ year doing web and I couldn't figure this out. Shame on me...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have to delete the question, cos its so stupid

Comment: I didn't think it was stupid. @Maadinsh should submit an answer for this, IMHO. The comment was well written.

Comment: ok then, let's let him do that. Also, better put just `//` in there, so that the SSL won't matter.

Comment: Right; `//` is the better method in order to automatically detect which environment it's in.

Comment: Also now this question is not related to codeigniter, nor php...

Comment: @DonJoe you'll need to ping them by addressing them as I have here to you.

Comment: @DonJoe so retag it then.

Comment: @Maadinsh I think you should post an answer here.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the [adding the original tags](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48612345/3) back in. To tell you the truth, I was on the fence as to adding them back in or other tag(s), but didn't know which one(s) to use. So yeah, both php and codeigniter tags are relevant to the problem.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I just knew that a question can't really be just about `href` :). I know nothing about PHP, so I knew you likely need to know something about `base_url()` to really get the question.

Comment: Right you are @Mike *cheers* - Side note: I made an edit to the answer in order to cover all the bases.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan IMO I don't think it's related to php or CI. You have a link returned as string (from first example). The function shouldn't matter.  Then you put the same string inside a text and inside a href. So this has to do just with the href or at most, html.
If the link was hardcoded instead of dynamic, the problem would be exactly the same

Comment: @Mike and Don. I added the "environment" tag since that is relevant and important to know.

Comment: @DonJoe yes they are relevant.

Comment: The answer provided demonstrates that knowing it is PHP and CodeIgniter is helpful to the question and answer. If it's not relevant, remove it from the question and remove the tags.

Comment: Did you set the base url in the config.php and autoloaded url helper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url is not returned twice by base_url().
If you don't specify the protocol, the browser treats it as a relative link, automatically prefixing it with the current domain and path.

A correct example would be this:

```
<h1><a href="//<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Link</a></h1>
```

According to CodeIgniter docs, it looks like you can also pass the protocol as second argument:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url

---

**Note:** It's also better to use `//` in there, so that the SSL won't matter.

Using `//` is the better method in order to automatically detect which environment it's in and to stay in.

Side note: When running scripts that are meant to be run inside a secure environment, also make sure that there are no `http://` references to scripts, images, css, etc., since this will contain mixed environments that some browsers will warn you about it.

Comment: Your side note is irrelivant to this issue as this issue should be properly handled by having a correct [CSP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests) set up.

Comment: @Martin that was my edit (see the comment in revisions), why would you think so?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The **note** bit is fine advice, but the side note implies the webmaster/mistress/sub needs to go through replacing all their internal `http:` links when (for this and many other security reasons) they *should* be simply implementing a **Content Security Policy** header, that includes an `upgrade-insecure-requests` directive `:-)`

Comment: @Martin I see. Well, in good coding practice, I use `//` as the base url and have taken the initiative in the past to have changed many. If by adding that directive is all that's needed, great. If you feel that the side note should be stricken, let me know and I'll do just that. ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I feel I've offended your sensibilities `:-(` that was not the intention. but this CSP header is intended to negate the need to manually update all the old `http://`links. And I'm sure CSP is coding best practise too `:-D`

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I do the same. Hardly ever you'll find `http` or `https` in my code. This is part of the "best practices" or "todo" list which I use on every project beginning.

Comment: @Martin can you ping me in a chatroom? This is an interesting subject and would like to talk it over with you, given if you have 5 mins. - and no, you haven't offended me *lol!* so no worries there.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I'm new here. Could I also join that room?

Comment: @DonJoe sure if you'd like, I think you have enough rep

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner How? Link, something? I don't know :(

Comment: @DonJoe I myself don't know or remember how to ping someone from inside a chat room *lol!* well, we'll see if Martin has time. I myself have some things to do now, like go playing guitar. Will check back in later. *ciao!*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164509/discussion-between-donjoe-and-funk-forty-niner).

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry I disappeared `:-/`

Comment: @Martin am here, see the "continue in chat" just above? am in there now.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner alas you were here but I was not `:-(` great minds are never free at the same time...